# Create one table out of multiple temp tables using SQL

Tags: sql

If it is possible, how to create one table/temp table out of multiple temp tables using SQL? Because creating a view is unfortunately not possible with temp tables.

For example, I have 3/more temp tables:

```
WITH a_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM a
    JOIN b
    WHERE ...
   )
, b_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM c
    JOIN d
    WHERE ...
   )
, c_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM c
    JOIN d
    WHERE ...
   )

SELECT * FROM a_table
UNION 
SELECT * FROM b_table
UNION 
SELECT * FROM c_table
```

How do I create just one table instead? Or have one view for all these unioned temp tables?

Tried to create a view but that is not possible with temp tables and the query that I have has like 50 temp tables.

Comment: Simply create a view. `create view myview as with a_table ...`.

Comment: Those are CTE's not temp tables. What version of SQL are you using? Pretty sure you can add that query as a view. View's are essentially queries stored as objects.

Comment: oh my bad. I've been searching for temp tables when they are CTEs. Thank you, jarlh and Jatin. This has solved the issue I'm facing. I have successfully created a view now not sure why it didn't work the first time.